# Matlab: Multiple assignment through logical indexing

Tags: matlab, indexing, variable-assignment

I am wondering if there is some way, how to multiple assign values to different variables according logical vector.

For example:

I have variables `a, b, c` and logical vector `l=[1 0 1]` and vector with values `v` but just for `a` and `c`. Vector `v` is changing its dimension, but everytime, it has the same size as the number of true in `l`.

I would like to assign just new values for `a` and `c` but `b` must stay unchanged.

Any ideas? Maybe there is very trivial way but I didn't figure it out.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: @JacubJon just for curiosity, if I understood your question right. Could you please check if my solution would also work? Because if it's an invalid solution I'd rather delete it.

Comment: @thewaywewalk, I didn't try your solution but I think we don't understand each other. In case I change logical vector 'l' to '[0 1 0]' means that I would like to assign new value just for variable 'b' and that means vector 'v' changed its dimension to 1 because it contains just new value for 'b'.. Is it clear now. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is, that you stored structured data in an unstructured way. You assume `a` `b` `c` to have a natural order, which is pretty obvious but not represented in your code.

Replacing `a` `b` `c` with a vector `x` makes it a really easy task.

```
x(l)=v(l);
```

Assuming you want to keep your variable names, the simplest possibility I know would be to write a function:

```
function varargout=update(l,v,varargin)
varargout=varargin;
l=logical(l);
varargout{l}=v(l);
end
```

Usage would be:

```
[a,b,c]=update(l,v,a,b,c)
```

Comment: Thanks, for sure, I can do that like this, but my variables a, b, c comes from different sources (structures) and I would like to keep continuity and make it in easiest way.